# How to add a character before each category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to show all the categories in my wordpress site

```
<?php wp_list_categories( array(
  'title_li' => '',
  'orderby'    => 'name'
) ); ?>
```

I wanted to add a `/` in between of each categories like

> All / Category 1 / Category 2 / Category 3

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#comment-1170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `separator` argument to specify what to use. Note that even if you specify a separator here, `wp_list_categories` still defaults to "list" style, so you need to reset that argument also. e.g.:

```
<?php wp_list_categories( array(
  'title_li'  => '',
  'separator' => '/',
  'style'     => '', 
  'orderby'   => 'name'
) ); ?>
```

Ref: [WP Code Reference for wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) (Note: the behaviour of this WP function is to add the separator to the end of *all* list items, even the last one)

Comment: I think your answer is correct because it is in the documentation but it's not working for me

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, I forgot to add the "style" argument too. I've updated my answer

Comment: Oh it's now working. Thank you very much. Will accept the answer in a minute

Comment: Downvote : Only problem is it adds the separator after the last term as well.

Comment: @Dev its a bit unfair to downvote an answer because you don’t like how Wordpress works! I didn’t write the wp_list_categories function - it is a built-in Wordpress function, so we have no control over the terms it adds the separator to.

Comment: Yes but it adds the sep after the last item when it shouldn't

Comment: Yes, sorry, its already locked in. I just worked out its a bug in core.